# Problems with date format and errors

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

data = pd.read_csv('CRUDE.csv')
data.columns = [['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume']]
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the error is elsewhere, when you do something with the data's index.

Comment: please post the full traceback of the error